# android replace delimeter with newline

Tags: android, stringtokenizer

I have a string which has  delimiter in it. I want to know the best way to replace the delimiter with a new line. I have had various issues with using the String Tokenizer the main problem being NoSuchElementException. Basically my approach thus far is to retrieve data from a database Once this has been achieved I store each of the records in a string  `String question = c.getString(1);` 
Here is the string tokenizer  `StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(question,"<ENTER>");` I loop through the tokens using a while loop

```
 while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                        System.err.println(st.nextToken());
                       // quest.setText(String.valueOf(st.nextToken("<ENTER>")));

            }
```

Working example in code

```
String in = "What is the output of: <ENTER><ENTER>echo 6 % 4;"; 

            in=in.substring(in.indexOf("<ENTER>")+7,in.lastIndexOf("<ENTER>"));
            String[] mSplitted= in.replaceAll("<ENTER><ENTER>", "<ENTER>").split("<ENTER>");

            for(int i=0;i<mSplitted.length;i++)
            {
                System.out.println("values: "+mSplitted[i]);
                quest.setText(String.valueOf(mSplitted[i]));
}
```

xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/quest"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="TextView" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.08"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

output

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can't you use `split()` of *String*.

```
String in = "<ENTER>title=Java-Samples<ENTER>" + 
            "<ENTER>author=Emiley J<ENTER>" + 
            "<ENTER>publisher=java-samples.com<ENTER>" + 
            "<ENTER>copyright=2007<ENTER>"; 

in=in.substring(in.indexOf("<ENTER>")+7,in.lastIndexOf("<ENTER>"));
String[] mSplitted= in.replaceAll("<ENTER><ENTER>", "<ENTER>").split("<ENTER>");
String mFinal="";

for(int i=0;i<mSplitted.length;i++)
{
   System.out.println("values: "+mSplitted[i]);
   mFinal= mFinal+ mSplitted[i];
}
quest.setText(mFinal);
```

Comment: I made the change and added in the new code. It is only returning copyright = 2007 and not the other parts of the string

Comment: See again, its doing perfectly fine.

Comment: i just rebuilt the project with the exact code that you gave me and only got the last fragement of of the string that is split

Comment: just cross verify by changing <TextView
        android:id="@+id/quest"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="TextView" />

Comment: i tried your edited answer. I also included the information from your comment. I added the android:singleLin="false" but i still only get copyright = 2007. could you post your exact code you used to create your result for the TextView. I want to see if you have any issues. I have used exactly the same code as you. I copy and pasted it.

Comment: it worked but it doesnt work with different strings What is the output of: <ENTER><ENTER>echo 6 % 4 i need the code to be more generic. For example the string here returns a blank

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind `NoSuchElementException` is that you are checking whether your Tokenizer has more tokens, but if it does, then you are reading two tokens at the same time.

Documentation says `hasMoreTokens` tests if there are more tokens available from this tokenizer's string. 
     If this method returns true, then a **subsequent** call to `nextToken()` with no argument will successfully return a token.

That means `hasMoreTokens` is only sure about the next token but not the token next to that!

Your condition should be..

```
while(st.hasMoreTokens()) { 
              String key = st.nextToken(); 
              String val="";
              if(st.hasMoreTokens())
                val = st.nextToken();  
            System.out.println(key + "\n" + val); 
        }
```

As your condition will work for only even number of elements.

Comment: for some reason only the last part of the string is displayed copyright=2007 the other parts are not displayed.